# Animation on sticky header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this code to make my site menu to stick at the top when scrolling.

It works, but I would like to add a text animation, similar to this site: http://somlaweb.com/

I mean to make the height of the menu smaller with an animation. How can I get this?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
       $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else {
       $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});
```

html

```
<header>
  <div class="header-banner">
    <a href="/" class="logo"></a>

    <h1>Visit Finland</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
      <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

css

```
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Say your `header` is equal to `height: 75px;` when `:not('.fixed-header')`, and equal to `height: 45px;` when `.fixed-header`, if you declare `transition: .7s` (for example) on `header`, you will have `header` "transition" or "animate" between those two values when the necessary classes are added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
       $('header').addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else {
       $('header').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 400vh;
  font-family: arial;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

header .header-banner{
  flex: 1;
}

header h1{
  font-size: 18px;
}

header ul li{
  display: inline;
}

header ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}

header.fixed-header{
  padding: 0px 10px;  
}

header.fixed-header h1{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header-banner">
    <a href="/" class="logo"></a>

    <h1>Visit Finland</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
      <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: add a transition to font-size to make it smoother.